# HTML to PDF using ironPDF getting error "access to the path 'IronPdf.ChromeRenderingEngine.dll' is denied." in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, html-to-pdf, ironpdf

We are using ironPDF to convert our document into PDF, it was working fine and was converting our documents (HTML) to PDF seamlessly in localhost, and after confirming everything we have bought a license of 1 year and uploaded the code to Production.

As soon as we have uploaded our code in Production, we are getting an error: access to the path 'IronPdf.ChromeRenderingEngine.dll' is denied.

Here is the code that we are using

```
   string file = $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "")}.pdf";
   IronPdf.License.LicenseKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IronPdf.LicenseKey"];
   IronPdf.Installation.TempFolderPath = ironPdf;
   var pdfPrintOptions = new PdfPrintOptions()
   {
       InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
       PaperOrientation = PdfPrintOptions.PdfPaperOrientation.Portrait,
       MarginTop = 10,
       MarginBottom = 10,
       MarginLeft = 10,
       MarginRight = 10,
       Footer = new SimpleHeaderFooter()
       {
           RightText = "Page {page} of {total-pages}",
           DrawDividerLine = true,
           FontSize = 10,
           FontFamily = "Open Sans"
       },
       CssMediaType = PdfPrintOptions.PdfCssMediaType.Print
   };
   var Renderer = new HtmlToPdf(pdfPrintOptions);
   var PDF = Renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(htmlContent.ToString());
   PDF.SaveAs($"{sourceUrl}{file}");
   PDF.Dispose();
```

Comment: I just got the same error today after purchasing and installing the license key. If i revert back to the trial license key, which worked a minute ago, i still get the same error

Comment: I restarted my server and it worked, but now the watermark is on the PDF. If i make any change, I get the error again, but then have to restart, but still have watermark

Comment: Yes, in free version it is working without any issue, but the problem is with Watermark.

Comment: Delete the dll, delete temporary files on server, do a clean install. 
Take license out of your web.config or app.config and initialize it before each instance you use it. Worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as this. I managed to solve it by setting the *temp folder path* to a location that the code could reach and write to (I believe it unpacks the libraries to it when it performs the generation). This is especially relevant when you're using an application service such as Azure or AWS.

For ASP.NET applications I put this in `Application_Start()` in `global.ascx.cs`:

```
IronPdf.Installation.TempFolderPath = Server.MapPath(@"/tmp");
```

For .NET Core I put this in `Startup` constructor.

```
IronPdf.Installation.TempFolderPath = @"/tmp";
```

Comment: Link to documentation for IronPdf.Installation.TempFolderPath

https://ironpdf.com/object-reference/api/IronPdf.Installation.html#IronPdf_Installation_TempFolderPath